# PDO get first element of a SQL query result

Tags: php, pdo

How do I get 7 from the table below with a query like:

```
SELECT name from table WHERE id = 3
```

That is, the first item of the array.

```
id name
1   [2,3]
2   [3,5,6]
3   [7,8]
```

This is how the PDO is looking like. I can get the

```
$db = new PDO('...');
$sth = $db->prepare('SELECT `name` AS grupo
FROM `table`
WHERE `id` =3');

$sth->execute();
$resultado= $sth->fetch();
echo ($resultado)[0];
```

Which is returning:

```
[7,8]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [PDO::fetchColumn](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

> Returns a single column from the next row of a result set

EDIT:

```
echo json_decode($sth->fetchColumn(), true)[0];
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the same result, because name is a single column

Comment: I don't think you can get the same result when `PDO::fetchColumn` returns single value. The example in the doc show exactly what you want to do http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetchcolumn-examples

Comment: You're storing name as JSON string `"[7,8]"`?

Comment: Ok, so you just need to decode it. I updated my answer.